Visual Studio 2022 (17.11.5) Find Dialog - Moving Cursor to Edit Window
In Visual Studio 2022 (17.11) and after updating to 17.11.5, I'm seeing a bug that's messing me up big time.
If I do a search via Ctrl-F, the search string will be found in the editor window in real time.  If the found string is currently displayed in the editor window (without scrolling) I can keep typing in the "find" dialog.
However, if the editor has to scroll to preview the found string (while I'm still typing), it moves the cursor to the edit window and I'm trashing my code while I'm continuing to type the search string.
Is there a fix?  Can I turn off this previewing of the find results?

It looks like this is happening when Visual Assist is active.  Any ideas?

Just found that this is a bug in the latest Visual Assist.
